# How are Functors useful?

Tags: scala, haskell, functional-programming, functor

We know that any generic type `F[_]` with`map` method, which complies to some [laws](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Functor+Laws.html), is a *functor*. For instance, `List[_]`, `Option[_]`, and `F[A] = Env => A` are functors. I am just wondering if this functor abstraction is meaningful.

How can I use the fact that they are functors ? Could you show an example of non-trivial computation, which would use the `map` and be actually useful ?

Comment: Check out http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~cis194/spring13/lectures/09-functors.html

Comment: Also http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Functor.html What do you consider non-trivial computation?

Comment: I think some people are misinterpreting Michael's question. I read it like this: he understands that functors abstract over the `map()` methods of a variety of different data types, but he's having a hard time understanding how one would *make use* of that fact. It's easy to think of contexts where *specific types* that are functors would appear and that why you'd *those types'* `map()` in those contexts. It's harder to think of contexts where you'd use a *type variable* restricted to `Functor` but with no other constraint!

Comment: @VictorMoroz Ok. You can show any computation of your choice and I will tell you whether it's trivial or not :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One of the biggest benefits of concepts like functions is that there are **generic constructions** that allow you to build more complex types out of simpler functors, and guarantee that these complex types have certain properties.  Functors understandably seem rather pointless when you consider them in isolation as you have done, but they become more and more useful the more such constructions you learn and master.

One of the simpler examples is that several ways of combining functors also yield a functor; e.g., if `List[A]` and `Option[A]` are functors, so are:

- **Composition of functors:** `List[Option[A]]` and `Option[List[A]]`
- **Products of functors:** `(List[A], Option[A])`
- **Sums of functors:** `Either[List[A], Option[A]]`

I don't know enough to write this out in Scala, but in Haskell facts like these translate into generic code like these examples:

```
-- A generic type to represent the composition of any two functors
-- `f` and `g`.
newtype Compose f g a = Compose { getCompose :: f (g a) }

-- If `f` and `g` are functors, so is `Compose f g`.
instance (Functor f, Functor g) => Functor (Compose f g) where
  fmap f (Compose fga) = Compose (fmap (fmap f) fga)
```

This is a very simple example, but:

- It's already useful as an *analytical tool* at least.  A *lot* of data types that people write in practice, when you look at them through the lens of this example, turn out to be products, sums or compositions of simpler functors.  So once you understand these constructions you can automatically "sense" when you write a complex type that it is a functor, and how to write its `map()` operation.
- The more elaborate examples have the same flavor:

  - We have a **generic construction** that guarantees certain contracts when instantiated with a type that implements `Functor`;
  - When we add a `Functor` implementation to any a type, we gain the ability to use that type in that construction.

A more elaborate example is [free monads](https://www.chrisstucchio.com/blog/2015/free_monads_in_scalaz.html) (link has an extended Scala example), a generic interpreter construction that relies on user-supplied `Functor`s to define the "instructions" for the language.  Other links (and these are mostly straight from a Google search):

- https://softwaremill.com/free-monads/
- http://underscore.io/blog/posts/2015/04/14/free-monads-are-simple.html

Comment: Thank you, Luis. Very interesting indeed. Could you give an example of a computation that uses just a `Functor` (aside from free monads) ?

Answer (score 6):

I don't know Scala, but in Haskell, the `Functor` class is essential to defining [Van Laarhoven-style lenses](http://www.twanvl.nl/blog/haskell/cps-functional-references):

```hs
type Lens' s a = forall f . Functor f => (a -> f a) -> s -> f s
```

These lenses are typically defined for specifically-related types `s` and `a`, but it's essential to their utility that they work with an arbitrary functor.

`Functor` is also important in its role as a superclass of `Applicative` and of `Traversable`. When working with these more powerful abstractions, it's often very useful to reach for the `fmap` method.

Answer (score 1):

Well, once you know something is a Functor, you don't just get `map`, you get all of the functions you can derive with it too

For example, it's possible to derive the function `lift` in a way that works for any functor.

Lift will "lift" a function from `A => B` to `F[A] => F[B]` for some Functor `F[_]` and is defined as

```
def lift[A, B](f: A => B): F[A] => F[B] = map(_)(f)
```

If you are using a library like [cats](https://github.com/typelevel/cats) or scalaz then you get these functions for free. The [cats documentation](http://typelevel.org/cats/tut/functor.html) has a few other examples you might be interested in

Comment: I don't disagree, but I'm not sure this really answers the question. In my experience it is pretty rare to have just a `Functor` constraint by itself in application code—if all you know is that `F` is a functor, then you pretty much have to have a signature like `F[A] => F[B]`, and at that point you should just be defining an `A => B` and mapping at the call site, where `F` is often going to be concrete or have other facts known about it.