# Examples of Functors composition

Tags: scala, functional-programming, composition, functor, scalaz

This is a follow-up to an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37931738/521070) to my previous question.

We know that functors compose. I can write a composition of functors `List[_]` and `Option[_]` using `scalaz` like this:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

scala> val flist = Functor[List]
flist: scalaz.Functor[List] = scalaz.std.ListInstances$$anon$1@a5f0295

scala> val foption = Functor[Option]
foption: scalaz.Functor[Option] = scalaz.std.OptionInstances$$anon$1@51e43ad4

scala> flist compose foption
res0: scalaz.Functor[[α]List[Option[α]]] = scalaz.Functor$$anon$1@94c02b

scala> val f = flist compose foption
f: scalaz.Functor[[α]List[Option[α]]] = scalaz.Functor$$anon$1@610bffa0

scala> val os: List[Option[Int]] = Some(1) :: Some(2) :: None :: Nil
os: List[Option[Int]] = List(Some(1), Some(2), None)

scala> f.map(os) {_ + 1}
res1: List[Option[Int]] = List(Some(2), Some(3), None)
```

Is it the correct way to compose functors with `scalaz` ?
Could you give a *real-life* example of a functors composition ?

Comment: Don't you repeat your existing question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31284131/how-to-simplify-nested-map-calls

Comment: Partially. I know how to compose functors now. Thanks for your answer, by the way :) Now I am interested in _real-life_ examples of functor composition.

Comment: Isn't mapping an option inside a list good enough?

Comment: No :) I need more ...

Comment: A functor is an abstraction which is too high level to give any interesting examples (different than simple nested lists/options etc). It's like asking "Give me a real-life example of java.lang.Object" :)

Comment: However there are interesting examples of composition of _applicative_ functors, which is a more concrete abstraction.

Comment: `Applicatives` are different story.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that you have a list of strings, where each string is a list of characters.  By composing the two list functors, you get *one* functor over lists of strings.  You can now map functions on characters, like, say, toUpper or toLower, to the list of strings.

Is this example realistic enough?:-)